# Use a button to manually scroll a paged UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a UIScrollView that has 10 images from an array. I need to scroll left or right to the next or previous image using the button

```
button scrollview button
   <     [ ... ]     >
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, this is how I was able to properly scroll a UIScrollView using a UIButton
The IF statements here assure that the scrollview wont go beyond the bounds of My NSArray of images.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Use a UIButton to scroll a UIScrollView Left or Right

-(IBAction)scrollRight{ 
    if(pos<9){pos +=1;
        [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(pos*scrollView.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"Position: %i",pos);
    }
}
-(IBAction)scrollLeft{  
    if(pos>0){pos -=1;
        [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(pos*scrollView.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"Position: %i",pos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, i only use 1 button for each method and they work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

set the contentOffset property of the scroll view to change the scroll position.

Comment: I've tried: 

    pos -=1;
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(pos*self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) animated:YES];

but this doesnt center the image

Comment: scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(100, 0);